# how to pass a reference to the current object in href?

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a reference to current element that is being clicked in `href` tag.

Consider this code which goes in a loop when creating a table

```
td=document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML='<a href="javascript: some_function(this,row_number,'extra_param')">click me</a>';
```

But `this` doesn't work because it points to the browser window so when I am setting it to something the whole page replaced the value I am setting it to. So how do I pass the reference to `<a>` object into `some_function()` ?

where `some_function()` is declared like:

```
function some_function(clicked_object,param2,param3) {
    clicked_object.style.backgroundColor="red"
}
```

Comment: `<a href="" onclick="some_function(this); return false;">click me</a>` A better way is to assign a click handler to `td` instead of inline code.

Comment: Assigning an id in the loop when table is created for each <a href  ...id which will be used afterwards by some_function?

Comment: @ChrisG Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar, but if I use `inline` code I can pass variable parameters for each row, besides `this`, something I can not do with event listeners

Comment: @Nulik I suspect you meant to send that to Chris G, not me. But the solution to that is to put the parameters in the element's `data-XXX` attributes, then the event listener can extract them.

Comment: @Barmar , do you know how do I set `data-XXX` in javascript? using `td.data-color` gives syntax error because `-` is invalid symbol for variable names

Comment: `td.dataset.color =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full fledged solution that avoids inline code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // create elements
  let td = document.createElement("td");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.innerHTML = `cell #${i}`;
  a.href = ""; // we need this so <a> appears as link
  // set click handler
  a.addEventListener("click", some_function);
  // add some data
  a.dataset.rowNumber = 1;
  a.dataset.extra = i * 2 + 7;
  td.appendChild(a);
  row.appendChild(td);
}

function some_function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop default event handling
  let clicked_object = e.target;  // get clicked element from event
  clicked_object.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  console.log("param:", clicked_object.dataset.extra);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: added data to elements

Comment: the problem is, that in my `href` I want to pass extra parameters. For example `some_function(this,"value_123456")` , and if I use event listeners I won't be able to pass a different parameter for each table row

Comment: You don't have to do it that way; you can put the parameter into the element's dataset: `a.dataset.myParam = 123;` then read it back in the click handler: `let value = clicked_object.dataset.myParam;`

Comment: I have edited the original question, so you can see, event listeners are not exactly the solution

Comment: @Nulik They still are. Added data to answer.

Comment: Note that dataset only has partial support in IE pre-11.  https://caniuse.com/#search=dataset